# C# AsParallel and Parallel: how to merge results less frequently?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, parallel-processing

C# AsParallel/Parallel: how to merge results less frequently?

For an example, a nested loop of lots iterations, acting as a parallel reduction. (or call it map reduce)

```
// Dictionary size is small and easily contend.
Dictionary<SumDataCategory, SumData> globalResult;
// A loop to be parallelized.
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
      // Pull inputs depending on i,j,k.
      InputData[] inputs = fetchInputData(i, j, k);
      // Do something independent calculation.
      SumData sum1 = SumData.Sum(inputs);
      // Finally reduction operation. <- to optimize
      globalResult[sum1.Category].Sum(sum1);
    }
  }
}
```

**The target is acquire the low-hanging fruit - improve reduction performance, with small effort. (not to rewrite the whole loop/processing body)**

**Constraint on the workload characteristics**:

- It is not completely regular: static partition should not be assumed.
- It is not highly dynamic: dynamic job/workload spawning is unnecessary.

Analysis:

- Per-iteration reduction to global state is a waste, and high cache contention.
  There are magnitudes more iterations/inputs than CPU cores.
- Manual partitioning, and handling partition is non trivial. (compared to vanilla AsParallel/Parallel or OpenMP)
  Because C# AsParallel/Parallel are libraries without compiler assistance (unlike OpenMP or data-parallel solutions), and most dirty work must be done by user.
- Even if partitioning is applied, per-chunk (partitioned data) reduction to global state is still a waste, and more complex. (compared to a final reduction, because final reduction can be serial or parallel, while per-chunk reduction is concurrent)

---

I could not think of a good solution:

- If I use thread-local, I cannot find a time to pull thread-local and merge them.
- If I do manual bookkeeping for per-thread results, I need a reliable thread-id and know id range ahead of time. (OpenMP and data-parallel solutions has them)

---

For reference, in OpenMP, I will do it like this:

- Before parallel loop, set or query threads count.
- Allocate per-thread reduction data.
- Parallel loop, and do thread local reduction by thread id.
- After the parallel loop, merge thread local results in serial or another parallel reduction (another parallel loop).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "per-unit merging." Can you give an example?

Comment: Could you edit the question and add an example of the parallel operation that you have in mind? Using either `Parallel` or `AsParallel` is OK. We just want to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JohnWu Updated, PTAL.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I added a serial loop example because IMO the serial one is the question.

Comment: What does the `Merge()` method do? Is that the same as concatenation?

Comment: @JohnWu Please consider it like arithmetic operation, e.g. sum/min/max. Not a big growing collection.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. There is nothing in your code example that mutates global data. If there is any sort of mutation going on, it is inside the `Merge()` or `Sum()` methods, which you seem hesitant to share. It's central to the question. Am I not understanding?

Comment: @JohnWu Any sensible Sum() implementation will mutate, as simple as `Sum(this SumData sumA, SumData sumB) { sumA.value += b.value; }`. It mutates because the globalResult is global - as long as it do stores anything into SumData, it mutates global data.

Comment: You can use `AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(x)` to set maximum number of threads, then do `.Aggregate(...)` to work with each partition separately and then aggregate result (you pass two functions there for this purpose)

Comment: @Evk Thanks. What is default value for AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism()? (Parallel.For()'s default seems to be unbounded?)

Comment: By default it's number of (logical) CPU cores. `Parallel.For` also has such setting (called `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`).

Comment: Also you likely don't want to parallelize the loops separately (I mean 3 times), better to combine them into 3-tuples (i,j,k) and parallelize that.

Comment: @Evk Yes, of course single parallelization over (i,j,k). Another PLINQ specific question: is there a built-in pattern/api for parallel flatten (e.g. ToList) (or prefix sum)? (unrelated to the given example)

Comment: @Evk Please create an answer with Aggregate and WithDegreeOfParallelism, so I could accept it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by parallel flatten? If you something like combining your 3 loops into one with 3-tuple then why do this in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first combine your loops into 3 tuple `(i,j,k)` and then run `AsParallel()` over that. To limit number of concurrent tasks handling operations in parallel, use `WithDegreeOfParallelism(x)`. So then your data will be partitioned, and each partition will be handled in parallel. To aggregate results from this partitions - use `Aggregate` function, but take care to use overloads provided for [ParallelQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0) and not regular `IEnumerable`. Example with simple sum:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
    .Aggregate(
    0, // initial seed
    (acc, value) => acc + value, // this is executed for accumulators in each partition, separately, updating partition accumulator
    (acc1, acc2) => acc1 + acc2, // this is to combine partition accumulators to get final one
    (acc) => acc); // this is to convert the final accumulator into final result (if necessary), so what will be returned
```

Comment: It seems that Parallel.For() does not honor MaxDegreeOfParallelism, while AsParallel() strictly honors WithDegreeOfParallelism(x).

Comment: The docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?view=net-6.0. state that it should limit number of concurrent operations to this value (so - less that or equal to that). I personally did not test that (but did test `WithDegreeOfParallelism` for that answer). What do you observe in your case?

Comment: I count the threads (id) that is ever seen during a Parallel.For() run.
Core, Framework, and Mono are all likely use more threads than MaxDegreeOfParallelism. (May be it is trying to be clever and detect thread blocking, but it is against common sense, fragile and likely to regress.) Mono and Core 6.0 on linux can easily go beyond  3*MaxDegreeOfParallelism.

Comment: But counting thread ids might be not a good idea because they get threads from a thread pool, not create new threads just for your task

Comment: It is a designated test to check those behavior, there is nothing else to interfere. And AsParallel() behaves as expected - for a not too short run, exactly x threads are used.